# Adhoc iOS App slower than Android App in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview

I am using in flutter in app webview in my application. On testing it on android and ios. The performance of android (release apk) application is better than ios one(adhoc ipa). I just need to know,

1. Can we improve the performace of ios app using test flight?
2. On stores what will be the policy of publishing the application which uses webviews?